# DIfference betweek Keras and Tensorflow for same dataset and hyperparameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have been experimenting with Keras and Tensorflow for the same dataset and same hyperparameters. My understanding was that Keras uses Tensorflow Library and the results will be similar. Below is the code in Keras for my model.

```
    model = Sequential()
    input_layer = Input(shape=(nf,))
    x = Dense(40, activation='relu',  use_bias=True)(input_layer)
    x = Dense(40, activation='relu',  use_bias=True)(x)
    output_layer = Dense(nl, activation='linear', use_bias=True)(x)

    model = Model(input_layer, output_layer)

    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=[coeff_determination])

    history_callback = model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=epochs,batch_size=batch_size, 
                                 validation_data= (x_valid,y_valid))
```

Here is the Tensorflow code:

```
hidden_1_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([INPUT_DIMENSION, 40])), 
'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([40]))}
hidden_2_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([40, 40])), 
'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([40]))}
output_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([40, OUTPUT_DIMENSION])), 
'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([OUTPUT_DIMENSION]))}

def neural_network_model(data):
    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['bias'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1) # leakyRelu(l1, alpha = 0.1)
    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['bias'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2) #leakyRelu(l2, alpha = 0.1)
    output = tf.matmul(l2, output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['bias']    
    return output

prediction = neural_network_model(x)  
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - prediction)) 
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)
with tf.Session() as Sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):   
        i = 0
        while i < len(x_train):    
           start = i
           end = i + BATCH_SIZE
           batch_x = np.array(x_train[start:end])
           batch_y = np.array(y_train[start:end])
           o, temp_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
```

When I compare the mse history with epochs, I found that the mse loss is two to three order of magnitudes less in Keras than in Tensorflow. Also, the convergence of Keras is faster (I need fewer epochs for Keras than Tensorflow). I am using the same batch size, same model architecture, and the dataset is also the same. Is this normal or Keras and Tesnorflow should give similar results? Thank you.